# How to change values using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do i go about changing the values inside the style for width and height using jquery?

```
<div id="id11t" style="position: relative; width: 1022px; height: 446px;">
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm just going to send you to http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/height/ on the off-chance you're serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#id11t').css({
  width: "300px",
  height: "200px"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id11t").css('width', '1022px');
$("#id11t").css('height', '1022px');
```

Will resize your div to 1022x1022

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id11t').width(X);
$('#id11t').height(Y);
```